# An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Signature specified is zero-sized. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131237)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

When I want to execute a stored procedure I have below error .  How can i fix it?

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Signature specified is zero-sized. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131237)

[image: error page]

[image: stored procedure]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post your code directly which generates this error? Thanks.

Comment: The Images of my error are Attached.

Comment: USE [Monasebat]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MyTest]    Script Date: 7/18/2018 9:10:40 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MyTest]
as 
select * from Monasebat

Comment: Have you tried to add `BEGIN` and `END` look like this `USE [Monasebat]
GO 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO ALTER procedure [dbo].[MyTest] 
as 
BEGIN
 select * from Monasebat
END`

Comment: Yes. I did it , but there is no diffrent

Comment: I reinstall it (solved)